# Excel - Using COUNTIFS - Count in Column A if Columns B equals and Columns C equal

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In ColA I have numbers from 1 to 4

In ColB I have Manager and Non Manager

In ColC I have Locations (London, Glasgow, New York etc.)

I'm trying, in Excel, to count the number of times `1` appears in ColA when ColB = `Manager` and ColC equals `Glasgow`.

I have tried the following but no joy:

```
=COUNTIFS('Data Sheet'!$A:$A,1,'Data Sheet'!$B:$B,"Manager",'Data Sheet'!$C:$C,"Glasgow")
```

Any help on where I am going wrong would be appreciated.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not explicitly defining the rows?  ala, `$A$2:$A$100`?  Or, why limit the column anyway, as well?  Are you stretching/carrying the function over horizontally as well?

Comment: The formula you are using looks fine, have you checked for leading or trailing spaces in each of the columns? And that the numbers in column A are actually formatted as numbers?

Comment: There can be anything from 100 rows to 000's of rows of data, hence not defining it in the formula.  Also, by using absolutes, the formula can be dragged across etc.

Comment: yeah i agree with jorden, i plugged this into a sample excel sheet and it worked. what is excel telling you is wrong with the formula?

Comment: We're all stumped, I think - What **are** you seeing happen when you plug in this formula?  Your `COUNTIFS` seems to be just what you needed.

Comment: OK, I've been reviewing the formula and data to see what's going on - stripped back the formula to simple counts to make sure all the data was correct and therein, for some reason, lies the problem. Basic counts were not working.  Have now cleaned the data, re-imported the data and now all working correctly.  GRRRRRR - apols all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you give this a try just to see if @Jordan was right with his assumption(s):

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text

Public Sub tmpSO()

Dim lngRow As Long
Dim lngLastRow As Long
Dim varArray As Variant
Dim rngFoundMatches As Range

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data Sheet")
    lngLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    varArray = .Range("A1:C" & lngLastRow).Value2
    For lngRow = LBound(varArray) To UBound(varArray)
        If Trim(UCase(varArray(lngRow, 1))) = "1" And _
            Trim(UCase(varArray(lngRow, 2))) = "Manager" And _
            Trim(UCase(varArray(lngRow, 3))) = "Glasgow" Then
                If rngFoundMatches Is Nothing Then
                    Set rngFoundMatches = .Cells(lngRow, "A")
                Else
                    Set rngFoundMatches = Union(rngFoundMatches, .Cells(lngRow, "A"))
                End If
        End If
    Next lngRow
End With
MsgBox "Found " & rngFoundMatches.Count & " matche(s):" & Chr(10) & rngFoundMatches.Address

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using Excel 2003, and COUNTIFS only started in Excel 2007

In Excel 2003, use SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--('Data Sheet'!$A$1:$A$10000=1),--('Data Sheet'!$B$1:$B$10000="Manager"),--('Data Sheet'!$C$1:$C$10000="Glasgow"))
```

Comment: Excel 2013 - should have said.